Regression table with objects of different class
I want to create a regression table using stargazer but with objects of different type. The challenge is that one of the models is a fixest class object, which is not supported by by stargazer.
I could extract the coefficient, standard errors, and other other statistics and manually paste them. The problem is that this is a laborious process and lead to downstream errors--I am expecting my dataset to grow so I don't want to go over every line every time.
My question is how to set up a routine to do this for me.
Here is what I am working with:
model.fixest <- feols(mpg ~ hp + drat + wt, data=subset(mtcars))

model.lm <- lm(mpg ~ hp + drat + wt + qsec, data=mtcars)

If stargazer supported fixest class objects, i could just run the following command but this is not possible.

stargazer(model.fixest, model.lm, omit.stat = c("f", "adj.rsq"), align= T, type="text")


Note how both models are very similar.
Thank you
